# Modifying the Page Numbers in the Table of Contents

Tags: table-of-contents, page-numbering

Is there a way how I could make a section/chapter/any-heading which occurs on page x in my document to appear in the table of contents with the page x-1? (I am using scrbook)

I'd like this result not for the entire document but only for a part of it.

General Example:

- Heading 1 of page 3 is listed in the ToC as starting on page 3. (x)
- Heading 2 of page 11 is listed in the ToC as starting on page 11. (x)
- Heading 3 of page 23 is listed in the ToC as starting on page **22**. (x-1)
- Heading 4 of page 47 is listed in the ToC as starting on page **46**. (x-1)
- Heading 4 of page 69 is listed in the ToC as starting on page 69. (x)

It might sound strange but I have good reasons for doing this:

Particular Context:

In my particular case I think I'll use this in the appendix (A) of the `backmatter`. The headings I am talking about there are sections:

```
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
x                              x                              x
x              \section*{فصل}  x  A.1 \section{Heading}       x
x                              x                              x
x                              x                              x
x                              x                              x
x                              x                              x
x                              x                              x
x                              x                              x
x                              x                              x
x 22                           x                           23 x
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
```

On page 22 I use `\section*{Heading}` for creating a section heading that is not listed in the ToC. On page 23 I use `\section{Heading}` to create a section heading that is listed in the ToC but which I would like to apeare there as starting on page 22.
The reason why I do this is that the text on page 22 is an Arabic text whose English translation is on page 23 but I want the english title in the ToC.

Comment: Please provide some context -- doing this for a `\chapter`, especially one that starts a new odd page, might be easier than for a `\section`.

Comment: @lockstep : I did provide some context.

Comment: Which document class are you using?

Comment: @GonzaloMedina : scrbook on LuaLaTeX

Answer (score 11, accepted):

you can suppress the automatically generated toc entry and replace it.

to suppress, add this command to your preamble:

```
\DeclareRobustCommand{\SkipTocEntry}[4]{}
```

if you are using hyperref, change the `[4]` to `[5]` -- this is the number of elements in the toc entry to be suppressed.

*immediately* before the line that generates the toc entry, insert the line

```
\addtocontents{toc}{\SkipTocEntry}
```

if applying it to a chapter, and you use `\include` to insert your chapters, it *must* be in the same file as the `\chapter` command; if you put it in the driver file, the timing will be off, and the chapter entry from the *next* chapter will be suppressed instead.

a replacement entry should be inserted immediately *after* the line that generated the toc entry, in order to ensure that the page number has been resolved correctly.
define a counter `\newcounter{prevpage}` in the preamble.  when setting up the replacement toc entry,

```
\setcounter{prevpage}{\value{page}}
\addtocounter{prevpage}{-1}
```

then use `\addtocontents{toc}{xxx}` where `xxx` is the line that was automatically generated (and suppressed) that you can copy from the `.toc` file, except that you should replace the assigned page number by `{\theprevpage}`.  if you had to `\protect` some commands in the text of the original heading, you should do the same in the replacement toc entry.

say this line appears in the toc (the example is from a test using `amsbook`):

```
\contentsline {section}{\tocsection {}{5}{Section title}}{10}
```

the page number is `{10}`.  what you'd put in your file as a replacement is

```
\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\contentsline {section}{\protect\tocsection {}{5}{Section title}}{\theprevpage}}
```

observe that `\contentsline` and `\tocsection` do need to be `\protect`ed.
(i took this example from a test using `amsart.cls`, but the principle should be the same regardless of the document class.  just copy what's in the `.toc` file from your first run, and modify it appropriately.)

**EDIT**: the OP created an admirable macro, `\transsection` to handle this.  what follows is a self-contained example file demonstrating the use of his macro with the `book` class.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{verbatim}

\DeclareRobustCommand{\SkipTocEntry}[4]{}
\newcounter{prevpage}

\newcommand{\transsection}[1]{%
  \addtocontents{toc}{\SkipTocEntry}%
  \section{#1}%
  \setcounter{prevpage}{\value{page}}\addtocounter{prevpage}{-1}%
  \addtocontents{toc}{%
    \protect\contentsline {section}{%
    \protect\numberline {\thesection}#1}{\theprevpage}}}

\begin{document}
\frontmatter
\tableofcontents

\mainmatter
\chapter{First}
\section{First section}
some text

\clearpage
\transsection{Test section}

We want this section to have a page number one less than the
real one.  This is from question 55645 in TeX.SX, where the
author is setting an Arabic page on the page before the
English translation page, and wants the TOC to show that
page number.

\vspace{1\baselineskip}
\verbatiminput{\jobname.tex}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I like your idea of creating the `prevpage`-counter but I don't know how I can "replace the assigned page number by `{\theprevpage}`" when I use `\addtocontents{toc}{xxx}` to create the entry.

Comment: @ClintEastwood -- i've added an example to the answer.  i hope it's clear now.

Comment: Thanks. I tried it now, but unfortunately it does not compile without error. I always get "the control sequence ... was never def'ed". When I click on "go to error" it shows me this passage of my *.toc-file: `\contentsline {section}{\tocsection {}{5}{Section title}}{53}`. the "53" is the correct prevpage, but it seems that he doesn't get the sectionnumber right. it should be `\numberline {B.2}` instead of `\tocsection {}{4}`. What I did is just copy and paste your example line in the document and added the lines for `prevpage`.

Comment: @ClintEastwood -- okay.  run the job without the `\SkipTocEntry`.  look in the `.toc` file, and copy out whatever line corresponds to the section whose number you want to change; that's the line that will have the correct information for the document class you're using.  (not all classes generate the same commands for the `.toc`, and you really need to match the one you're using.) change the page number to `{\prevpage}`, and you may have to add `\protect` in front of `\numberline`.  then insert the `\SkipTocEntry` and rerun (twice).

Comment: I finally understood your solution. Sorry that it took a while... It is really nice and works: I created a new command: `\newcommand{\transsection}[1]{\addtocontents{toc}{\SkipTocEntry}\section{#1}\setcounter{prevpage}{\value{page}}\addtocounter{prevpage}{-1}\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\contentsline {section}{\protect\numberline {\thesection}#1}{\theprevpage}{section.\thesection}}}`. However, there is one last problem: For some reason the prevpage-counter does not resolve the pagenumbers correctly. When I replace `\theprevpage` with `\thepage` it resolves them correctly...

Comment: to be more precise: when I replace `\theprevpage` within the `\addtocontents` with `\thepage`, then the pages are correctly resolved. If, however, I delete `\addtocounter{prevpage}{-1}`, leaving `\prevpage` in the `\addtocontents` with the `\value{page}` I get wrong numbering.

Comment: @ClintEastwood -- i'm afraid i don't understand the problem you describe; i can't reproduce the wrong page number.  i've added a full self-contained example to the answer that shows that your macro (a very nice one!) works.  i omitted the last `{section.\thesection}` since that really isn't needed in the toc.

Comment: oh, I see. Using your example, it does work on my machine, too. I still doesn't get the prevpage-counter right in the large tex-file-abyss I am normally working in. The more I think about it, the more I am sure, that the error is caused because I am using ledmac/ledpar to get the text with my translation on facing pages: In this case, it sets the counter to the page where ledpar's `\begin{pages}` resides. Still weird, though, that replacing `\theprevpage` with `\thepage` gets the correct page (x). I must find another way to substract 1 from thepage **inside** the `\addtocontents` to get (x-1).

Comment: @barbara beeton, is it possible to implement the same on the bibliography environment? thanks.

Comment: @GokulKishan -- in the toc, there's an advantage that the entry consists of a command with well structured arguments.  in most bibliography corpora -- once the data gets into the tex file -- you have only a `\bibitem` followed by what may as well be free form text (well, an item *does* usually, fairly reliably if `makeindex` is used, end with a blank line, equivalent to `\par`), so being able to isolate it reliably is possible, but much less certain.  i'd guess ignoring an item is possible, but probably not easy.  this is certainly a good topic for a new question, so please post one.

Answer (score 4):

The following example shows a way to do this for `section`.

To use the special section I define the command `\specialsection`. It's important to use `\makeatletter` for the table of contents.

```
\documentclass{scrbook}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand\@pnumwidth{3.55em}
\let\@dottedtoclineorig\@dottedtocline
\def\local@dottedtocline#1#2#3#4#5{%
  \ifnum #1>\c@tocdepth \else
    \vskip \z@ \@plus.2\p@
    {\leftskip #2\relax \rightskip \@tocrmarg \parfillskip -\rightskip
     \parindent #2\relax\@afterindenttrue
     \interlinepenalty\@M
     \leavevmode
     \@tempdima #3\relax
     \advance\leftskip \@tempdima \null\nobreak\hskip -\leftskip
     {#4}\nobreak
     \leaders\hbox{$\m@th
        \mkern \@dotsep mu\hbox{.}\mkern \@dotsep
        mu$}\hfill
     \nobreak
     \hb@xt@\@pnumwidth{\hfil\normalfont \normalcolor \the\numexpr#5-1\relax~(x-1)}%
     \par}%
  \fi}
\newcommand\specialsection[2][]{%
\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\let\protect\@dottedtocline\protect\local@dottedtocline}
   \ifx\relax#1\relax
       \section{#2}
   \else
      \section[#1]{#2}
  \fi
\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\let\protect\@dottedtocline\protect\@dottedtoclineorig}
}
\makeatother


\begin{document}
\makeatletter
\tableofcontents
\makeatother
\chapter{foo}
\backmatter
\chapter{foo}
\section*{arabic}
text in arabix
\clearpage
\specialsection{english}
text in English

\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: while you were answering I added some context to my initial question. So I 'd like t ask: does this also work with `scrbook` and sections? your solution seems nice!

Comment: @ClintEastwood: I edited my answer.

Comment: @MarcoDaniel, I am very interested to use your solution, to @ClintEastwood's question, on the `article` documentclass. I looked at your initial answer from 13:41, where you used the `report` class, but I can't seem to get it to work. Would you be able to make an example using the `report` class? Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You can fill in your table of contents manually for each section like this:

```
% When you create a new section in your text

\section*{Your section name string} % the asterisk needed.

\addtocontents
{toc}
{  \protect\contentsline{section}
   {Your section name string}
   {\number\numexpr\the\value{page} - 1\relax} % There is \thepage-1 value.
}

% The text of your section's here...
```

The code is the slightly changed code of **\addcontentsline** command. Its original code can be seen in terminal like this:

```
texdef -t latex addcontentsline
```

Comment: Sweet! Finally resolved my issue. Thanks.
But I found out the compiler hints an error in sharelatex, I appended an empty `{}` within the second curly braces. Now the code looks like:
```\addtocontents
{toc}
{  \protect\contentsline{section}
   {Your section name string}
   {\number\numexpr\the\value{page} - 1\relax}
  {}
}```